# Tkinter displays labels incorrectly

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I was tasked to create a program where you run your own drug cartel (Very PC) and there's a group of labels and a button on one side of the window where you are able to buy items, each item is part of a class and labels and buttons are made for said items within the class. Tkinter will occasionally put these labels in the correct order, but randomly Tkinter will not place anything at all for some items.

Ive tried changing around the way the labels get placed however i haven't gotten anywhere. Nothing seems to work.

Here's the class where the labels and buttons are generated for each item.

```
class drug:

    def __init__(self, name, potency, duration, safety, buy):

        self.name = name
        self.origin = ('Brighton', 'London', 'Netherlands', 'China', 'USA', 'Mexico')[ran.randint(0, 5)]
        self.potency = potency
        self.duration = duration
        self.safety = safety
        self.buy = buy
        self.seller = None
        self.paneltitle = Label(mainFrame, text=self.name, font=('Segoe UI', 20, 'bold'))
        self.panellocation = Label(mainFrame, text=self.origin, font=('Segoe UI', 12, 'bold italic'))
        self.panelprice = Label(mainFrame, text='$' + str(self.buy) + ' (/g)', font=('Segoe UI', 12, 'bold italic'))

        self.buybtn = ttk.Button(mainFrame, text='Purchase')

    def place_gen_panel(self, x, y):

        self.paneltitle.place(x=x, y=y)
        self.panellocation.place(x=x, y=y+30)
        self.panelprice.place(x=x, y=y+60)
        self.buybtn.place(x=x, y=y+90)
```

Below is the code which runs place_gen_panel() with parameters that are calculated from the very simple for i in range loop.

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    obj = drug()
    master_list.append(obj)
    obj.place_gen_panel(10, i*130)
```

I'm not of a high enough reputation to post images so ive included links instead

This is the program when it decides it wants to work

[image]

https://i.ibb.co/gmCw21t/Screenshot-2019-09-18-at-06-29-19.png

And this is what happens most of the time, it isnt always the middle item that goes, and sometimes only one item is displayed

[image]

https://i.ibb.co/HF22DD8/Screenshot-2019-09-18-at-06-29-39.png

Thank you all so much for your time, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: at start you can use `print()` to see values in variables - maybe they have wrong values. Maybe you have empty strings so it put empty places.

Comment: BTW: you can use `self.origin = radom.choice(('Brighton', 'London', 'Netherlands', 'China', 'USA', 'Mexico'))`

Answer (score 2):

It is generally best to avoid excessive use of `place` since it requires lot of calculations to make your widget appear precisely at where you want them to be. Using `pack` or `grid` are much preferred since tkiner will manage the positions for you.

What I recommend is to change your `drug` class so it inherits from `tk.Frame`. Then you don't have to deal with overlapping widgets once you get the geometry right.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random as ran

class Drug(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args):
        super().__init__(master)
        name, potency, duration, safety, buy = args
        self.name = name
        self.origin = ('Brighton', 'London', 'Netherlands', 'China', 'USA', 'Mexico')[ran.randint(0, 5)]
        self.potency = potency
        self.duration = duration
        self.safety = safety
        self.buy = buy
        self.seller = None
        self.paneltitle = tk.Label(self, text=self.name, font=('Segoe UI', 20, 'bold'))
        self.panellocation = tk.Label(self, text=self.origin, font=('Segoe UI', 12, 'bold italic'))
        self.panelprice = tk.Label(self, text='$' + str(self.buy) + ' (/g)', font=('Segoe UI', 12, 'bold italic'))
        self.buybtn = ttk.Button(self, text='Purchase')

    def place_gen_panel(self):
        for num, widget in enumerate((self.paneltitle, self.panellocation, self.panelprice, self.buybtn)):
            widget.grid(row=num)

master_list = []

mainFrame = tk.Tk()

for i in range(3):
    obj = Drug(mainFrame, "A","B","C","D","E")
    obj.grid(row=i)
    master_list.append(obj)
    obj.place_gen_panel()

mainFrame.mainloop()
```